# cannot run catkin build on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ros, catkin

I have **Ubuntu 20.04** and I've just installed ROS **noetic** and catkin.

But each time I do `catkin build` and I have a list of errors and cannot proceed. Can you guys please help me solve this problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkin", line 5, in <module>
    from catkin_tools.commands.catkin import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py", line 28, in <module>
    from catkin_tools.common import is_tty
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/catkin_tools/common.py", line 23, in <module>
    import trollius as asyncio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/trollius/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/trollius/base_events.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import tasks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/trollius/tasks.py", line 565
    def async(coro_or_future, loop=None):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This isn't a  catkin issue. Your python file has a syntax error. Since this is an installed package it is most likely because you're using the wrong version of Python. What does your `CMakeLists.txt` and the surrounding lines in that file look like?

Comment: yes thank you... the problem was indeed with the python pkg... because i had 2 versions of python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> apt and pip3 versions of catkin_tools are broken for noetic.
> Workaround is to install like this:
>
> ```
> sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools.git
> ```

Refer to; https://github.com/Rayman/ros-get/issues/95

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install catkin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3-rosdep-modules : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg-modules (>= 0.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
python3-rosdistro-modules : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg-modules but it is not going to be installed
python3-rospkg-modules : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg-modules but it is not going to be installed
ros-noetic-rospack : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).